# How use czech language in emWin library

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding

I tried to use the Czech language in my project based on the emWin library. Regarding the Unicode chapter (subchapter of 'Language support') I used GUI_UC_SetEncodeUTF8(). Now I can display letter like ö or á but I cannot display č, ž , ď or ů (and more). Slovak letter  "ô" can be displayed also.

I found U2C.exe to convert the text and also checked with a different [online converter](http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html) or [table](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) and the conversation of letters are right.

I wrote letters in LISTVIEW, DROPDOWN or TEXT fields.

Is there some limitation of letters can be used? I do not know where could be the problem.

Comment: Does your font support those letters?

Comment: I use format GUI_FONT_20_1 ,  can see now it not support all letters. (https://www.segger.com/cms/admin/uploads/imageBox/emWin_Fonts_GUI_Font20_1.gif) . How can i change it ? Is only possible way to solve this issue to create my own font?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know emWin well enough to answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your font with fontCvt software at first then append its file to your project then use its characters any where. I think,since some of your used characters exist in some pre-defined fonts of emWin, you could display them. 
And the answer of your second question is NO, there is no limitation of letter in any emWin widgets. 
Tell me if you need any help in creation your font file.